# How can I view which answers have the lowest vote scores?

Tags: support, answers, search

I was wondering if there is a way that I can search and view a list of answers that is sorted by vote scores, in such a way that I can determine which answers have the lowest scores?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can figure this out yourself; [just search](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer%20score%3a..-1)  and then go to the last page.

Of course, one would tend to assume that answers with the absolute *lowest scores* have probably been deleted.

Comment: Ok, I hadn't realized that. Thanks!

Comment: I edited because of the change in the question - hope this is ok with you Shog9 - comment to me and I will change it back if you want it changed back and can't do it yourself - don't understand - looks like you are a moderator with 101 reputation...

Comment: @tom [Shog9](http://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) is an SE team member and is a mod everywhere.